# Insertion values for an empty binary tree

Tags: binary-tree

I have a problem related to binary trees.

[image]

They have given that

Starting from an empty binary search tree, the insertion of which of the following sequences of integer keyscould produce the binary tree above?

Could someone please kindly explain the logic behind this.

The answer is given as 
5, 3, 4, 9, 1, 7.. Can someone please explain how this could be.

Comment: There is no specified scheme for where elements go in a binary tree. What you probably want to know is how it works in a binary *search* tree.

Answer (score 0):

When inserting a node in a binary search tree, you compare it to each node starting from the root. If it is greater than the current node, go down the right branch and insert it there. Otherwise, go down the left branch and insert it there. If there is no branch then you have found the place to insert the node.

Follow this rule starting from an empty tree and try to the given values until you get the tree they gave you.

Comment: The answer is given as 5, 3, 4, 9, 1, 7 . how can it be.

Answer (score 0):

You only show a sequence. No other to select?

There are several sequences that could produce a binary search tree.

Given any binary search tree, an insertion sequence that produces it is its preorder traversal.

The reason is that during the insertion **the nodes already inserted never change of position**. Each new node that you insert is placed as a child of an incomplete node.

The insertion of symmetrical preorder traversal, that is, visit the root, then visit in preorder the right subtree and finally visit in preorder the left subtree also produces the same tree.

At in general the insertion of any variant of a preorder traversal produces the original tree.

Also, the insertion of level traversal, that is, first the root, then the nodes of second level, and so on produces the original binary search tree. Note that you can permute the nodes of a same level and the result will be the same.